# VirtualBox disk full on importing appliance in ova

Tags: virtualbox

trying to import MyMachine.ova (Ubuntu created on VBox and exported to ova) I am catching error:

> Failed to import appliance D:\Exported Virtual
>   Machines\MyMachine.ova.
>
> Could not create the imported medium 'D:\VirtualBox
>   VMs\MyMachine\MyMachine-disk1.vmdk'.
>
> VMDK: cannot write allocated data block in 'D:\VirtualBox
>   VMs\MyMachine/MyMachine-disk1.vmdk' (VERR_DISK_FULL).
>
> Result Code: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80BB0004) Component: ApplianceWrap
>   Interface: IAppliance {8398f026-4add-4474-5bc3-2f9f2140b23e}

I have C drive and D drive, my C is main drive and there is little space, but on D I have ~110 GB free space so it isn't a problem in space.

Configuration for virtualbox path is **File->Preferences->Default machine folder: D:\VirtualBox VMs**

And after clicking File->Import appliance I have: **Virtual Disk Image D:\VirtualBox VMs\DanfossMachine\DanfossMachine-disk1.vmdk**

So it seems that it should work without any problem, but it fails :(

Could someone maybe give a hint?

Comment: In my case, I had to change the drive where virtual disk image file(vmdk) is created. It might be there is not enough space in which a default disk drive is chosen.
- Good luck -

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple possible solutions :

- Make sure your target file system is NTFS and not something with a 4GB file limitation (eg FAT32)
- Uncompress the ova file using 7zip or similar. Create a new virtual machine and import the vmdk that came from the ova as the VM's hard drive during creation. This ought to tell you how large the existing hard drive is. It's possible that your "MyMachine-disk1.vmdk" has a reserved file space much larger than the actual ova file takes up, and thus will run into a disk full error despite not appearing to need that much space.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me, too. My HDD is about 237GB of which ~50GB was used by the System. I was copying the .ova file (~72GB) into my hard disk (from an external drive, thinking it would speed up the process) and then was trying to import it. As a result, it was taking 2x the space.

The problem was resolved as I (deleted the .ova file from my drive) and imported the image directly from the external drive. I didn't get the error message anymore. Hope it helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Many days ago i came up with this solution, hope it helps

I did this under Ubuntu Server 20.04

````
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv

exit

sudo resize2fs /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv```
````